# Compilation errors in a CUDA C project (nvcc compiler)

Tags: linux, cuda, compiler-errors, nvcc

I am working on a CUDA C project, adding new functionalities step by step.
Everything was going fine until I added to the code a particular kernel: the nvcc compiler now gives me 4 errors, all related to the same kernel (the new one).
Here are the error-generating lines:

```
__global__ void update(float* original, float* new, float* current, int nhalf) {  // line 104
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;  // line 105
  if (i < nhalf) {  // line 106
    current[i] /= nhalf;  // line 107 
    new[i] = (original[i] < current[i]) ? current[i] : original[i]; // line 108  
  }
}
```

Since I write the kernel bodies before the main function, I don't use prototypes.

In the main function I launch the kernel at line 384:

```
update<<<p->gridSize,p->blockSize>>>(p->deviceEnv, p->deviceTrueEnv, p->deviceSmoothTrueEnv, Nhalf);
```

The first three arguments are pointers to float, while the fourth argument is just an integer number.

When I try compiling with nvcc I get the following errors:

```
project.cu(106): error: expected a ")"
project.cu(107): error: identifier "current" is undefined
project.cu(108): error: expected a type specifier
project.cu(384): error: too many arguments in function call
```

I use the following bash command to compile:

```
nvcc -O0 -shared -o libproject.so project.cu -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -I$HOME/include/csound -arch=sm_30 -I/usr/local/cuda/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcufft -g -G
```

I am really confused, also because in the very same project I have many other kernels which are very similar and they compile all right. I launch them without any problems in the same exact way.
Can somebody please help me identifying the problem here? Many thanks in advance.

PS: I am using the cuda toolkit 7.0 on Ubuntu.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in c++.  Change that parameter name to something else, like `my_new`, both at the parameter and for usage within the `update` function body.

Comment: Aaargh, so simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RobertCrovella, by the way, do you think there is a better way to find the  element-wise max of two arrays? I am wondering whether this is a low performance solution or not... (thanks again for answering all these cuda-related questions)

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by using a variable in a kernel whose name conflicted with a reserved keyword (`new` in this case).

[This community wiki answer has been added from comments to get this question off the unanswered list].